# Scala implicit class to Java static method for interop?

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-java-interop

Is it possible to automatically generate companion Java static methods for interop from an implicit class definition ?

e.g.:

```
class Foo()
object FooOps {
    implicit class FooOps(foo: Foo) extends AnyVal {
      def baz = "hello"
    }
}
```

can be invoked as `new Foo().baz`. However this is rather inconvenient and non-idiomatic in Java. Is it possible to auto-generate (e.g. via macros) static methods for Java's sake, like Kotlin does for extension methods ? e.g.:

```
object FooOps {
    @MagicAnnotation 
    implicit class FooOps(foo: Foo) extends AnyVal {
      def baz(n: Int) = "hello"
    }
    // generated:
    def baz(foo: Foo, n: Int) = foo.baz(n)
}
```